# Product has no $9$ amongst its digits

Tags: number-theory

> What is the smallest positive integer $N$ such that the product of $999999$ and $N$ in decimal notation has no $9$ amongst its digits?

I first saw that $999999 = 10^6-1$, but how do we relate this to having $9$ among the digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$999999\cdot N=10^6N-N=10^6(N-1)+(10^6-N)$

For $N<10^6$, this number is composed of the digits of $N-1$ and the digits of $10^6-N$ padded to the left with zeros to 6 digits.

So both $(N-1)$ and $(10^6-N)$ should not contain the digit $9$

But $(10^6-N)$ does not contain the digit $9$ iff its $9's$ complement 
(padded in front with zeros to 6 digits) $999999-(10^6-N)=N-1$ does not contain zeros

The smallest $N$ with this property is $N-1=111111$

Which gives $N=111112$

Comment: I added more explanations. Is it enough?